# Is there a branch history in git?

Tags: git, version-control

Scenario : I am working on my branch which unfortunately has an odd naming convention. To assist a few other developers I `checkout` their branches - fix some code and `push` the changes. I had to do this for a few developers and now, I don't remember which branch I was originally working on. 
`git branch` shows a list of all the 50 branches I have worked on thus far. 
Is there a way I can know which branch I was originally working on ? Does git maintain a branch history sorted by date that I can visit ? Even if there is a way to know which branch I was working on prior to the current branch I am on, it would be helpful.

Comment: `git reflog` is your friend

Answer (score 4):

If you run `git reflog` you will see messages similar to this when you switch between branches:

```
012345 HEAD@{6}: checkout: moving from FeatureOneBranch to AnotherExampleBranch
```